# Draw string on oval

Tags: java, swing, awt

I must write a text on an oval or circle
I have this code(I found it on Stackoverflow) but I don't understand some points.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panneau extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        // Declaration 
        String text = "test";
        int x = 100, y = 50;
        int ovalWidth = 50, ovalHeight = 50;

        // Draw circle
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillOval(x-ovalWidth/2, y-ovalHeight/2,ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
        // I don't understand why x-ovalwidth/2 and y-ovalheight/2

        // Put text into circle
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        double textWidth = fm.getStringBounds(text, g).getWidth();
        // What is the job of getstringbounds 
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(text, (int) (x - textWidth/2),(int) (y + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2));
    } 
}
```

and thanks

Comment: I don't understand why we write : x-ovalWidth/2 and not just x, and I don't know the job of getstringbounds

Comment: Yes sorry, just noticed your comments

Comment: Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` otherwise you will end up with unwanted paint artificates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using information from the [Graphics Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
fillOval( x, y, width, height)

x - the x coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be filled.
y - the y coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be filled.
width - the width of the oval to be filled.
height - the height of the oval to be filled.
```

So you are telling the graphics to draw a circle where the top-left is at x - (half the width), y - (half the height). Reason being, it offsets the circle so the center of the circle is at (x, y) instead of the top-left.

[getStringBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getStringBounds%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Graphics%29)

```
Returns:
a Rectangle2D that is the bounding box of the specified String in the
specified Graphics context.
```

(Returns a rectangle that is big enough for the String)

Needless to say, the documentation is very helpful to look at when you are using various java classes.

Comment: thanks so much , so for the first one the center of cercle is in (x,y) and x,y is where we will put the text because i see  g.drawString(text, (int) (x - textWidth/2),(int) (y + fm.getMaxAscent()/2));

Comment: Right, so you are placing the center of circle and the center of the text at the same (x,y)